# iPhone Network Discovery

Tags: iphone, objective-c, networking, ios4

I'm trying to do a sort of network discovery using the iPhone.

By that I mean I want for example a list of all the computers in the LAN that the iPhone is connected by wireless, and the list should contain the ip's and MAC addresses of any powered on computers that may be in the LAN.

What's the best approach on this?

*(any code would be appreciated)*

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider trying to implement netstat on the device. You'll want to use reachability to ensure that you're only checking when the device is on a LAN.

Depending on the network, consider using Apple's bonjour service to discover services running on networked computers.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Like Jeremy said above, you could look into using Bonjour. I'm not too familiar with Bonjour, so I'm not sure if it will pick up on every machine on a LAN, or if it will only pick up devices that have published services via Bonjour, like printer sharing or SMB file shares.

That said, it's probably a good place to get started, as the Apple docs have some good code samples. In particular, you may be interested in the [NSNetServices and CFNetServices Programming Guide: CFNetServices - Browsing For Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/CFNetServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000229-66600) article. There's a code sample there ;-)